magento 2.4.6 knockout.js:3753 Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "visible: function(){return isVisible() }"
in magento 2.4.6 getting bellow error. i can not found solution so if anyone can help me then it will be great.
knockout.js:3753 Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "visible: function(){return isVisible() }"
Message: isVisible is not a function
at visible (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:3221:28), :3:67)
at update (knockout.js:5519:59)
at ko.dependentObservable.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved (knockout.js:3745:45)
at Function.evaluateImmediate_CallReadThenEndDependencyDetection (knockout.js:2331:115)
at Function.evaluateImmediate_CallReadWithDependencyDetection (knockout.js:2288:41)
at Function.evaluateImmediate (knockout.js:2253:40)
at ko.computed.ko.dependentObservable (knockout.js:2085:40)
at knockout.js:3743:40
at Object.arrayForEach (knockout.js:168:36)
at applyBindingsToNodeInternal (knockout.js:3715:34)
Error screen-shot : https://app.screencast.com/5nfC8SUFh1zUZ
error screen-shot 2 : https://app.screencast.com/GYu56tBdg7Rbd
file path : magento2-2.4.6\lib\web\knockoutjs\knockout.js
Thanks

maybe check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/282651/after-updating-to-magento-2-3-2-checkout-page-throws-error
